# Error "Server Error in '/' Application for undefined scalar variable of stored procedure

Tags: mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have problem in Delete templated field in grid view. When i clicked on delete its gave an error:- (

> Must declare the scalar Variable "@User_Id"

)

HTML code..

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db1ConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [User_table] WHERE [User_Id] = @User_id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [User_table] ([User_Id], [First_name], [Last_name], [User_Type], [Email_id], [Password], [Confirm_password], [Created_date]) VALUES (@User_Id, @First_name, @Last_name, @User_Type, @Email_id, @Password, @Confirm_password, @Created_date)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [User_table]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [User_table] SET [User_Id] = @User_Id, [First_name] = @First_name, [Last_name] = @Last_name, [User_Type] = @User_Type, [Email_id] = @Email_id, [Password] = @Password, [Confirm_password] = @Confirm_password, [Created_date] = @Created_date WHERE [User_Id] = @User_Id">
```

SQL Stored procedure

```
create proc insert_user_tb
@usrid varchar(5),
@fstname varchar(10),
@lstname varchar(10)
,@usrtype varchar(5)
,@emailid varchar(20)
,@pss varchar(10)
,@cnfpass varchar(10)
,@created varchar(10)
As
begin
insert into User_table(User_Id,First_name,Last_name,User_Type,Email_id,Password,Confirm_password,Created_Date) 
values (@usrid,@fstname,@lstname,@usrtype,@emailid,@pss,@cnfpass,@created)
end
```

I am trying to solve this error from many days.

Comment: where/how did you define "@User_id" you're using in DeleteCommand ?

Comment: I can't see you're using insert_user_tb sp anywhere! however it's irrelevant to the error  you're trying to fix.